# how to customize bootstrap button and add small images in it?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to customize bootstrap button and add two small images in the button itself to make it look like button. 
Here is the image preview: 
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLqYQ.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried where you got stuck to display the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<button type="submit" style="background-color:red;"><img src=""> Button<img src=""></button>
```

It seems simple enough